# Have first login screen able to do landscape mode (rotate)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, login, android-app

When I first brought up the Android App, the first page asking for Open-ID provider came up in 'Portrait' mode and the screen wouldn't rotate (I almost always use my table in Landscape).  After that first page, all the rest worked fine.  I think we should also allow the first page to rotate.

Version 0.1.50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, I just ran the app on a tablet and wow that leads to a bad experience. The screen rotated 3 times just for me to login, then finally went to the landscape mode after I finished logging in. Thanks for reporting this! It's been fixed and will be live in version 0.1.53 coming out later tonight.